# Cannot get IPv6 addresses returned from DNS64 (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, dns, ipv6

In light of Apple's recent announcement that all new mobile apps need to support "IPv6-only" in June, I am using their DNS64/NAT64 setup (described [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=nat64%2Fdns64%20apple&oq=nat64%2Fdns64%20apple&gs_l=serp.3...4220.4771.0.4817.6.5.0.0.0.0.93.276.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..3.2.183...0i30j0i22i30.XCkkJimeHTk)) to try and test my app.

I am not able to get DNS64 to work properly with this setup. In particular, when I try to do a DNS lookup on any address using getaddrinfo(), I get EAI_NONAME.  Here is the exact code I am using:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; /* Stream socket */
hints.ai_flags = 0;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */ 

int result;
struct addrinfo *addrinfo;

NSString *hostString = @"yahoo.com";

result = getaddrinfo([hostString UTF8String], NULL, &hints, &addrinfo);

if (result == 0) {
    NSLog(@"worked");
    struct sockaddr_storage stor = *( (struct sockaddr_storage *) addrinfo->ai_addr);
    NSLog(@" result = %@", [AppDelegate inet_ntoa_r:stor]);
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"bad, error = %i (%@)", result, hostString);
}
```

I know this code is correct since when I switch to my local internet provider, I am actually able to get a IPv6 address returned for yahoo.com. However, I don't think this is the "IPv6-only" environment Apple is looking for, so I want to get things working with their NAT64/DNS64.

To verify, I tested with the IPv6 Toolkit App on the App Store, and see the same results.

At this point I am thinking there is some extra configuration required for DNS64, but I'm not sure what it would involve.

EDIT: Testing the site [test-ipv6](http://test-ipv6.com) through this DNS64 gives the error "Our test show that you will have a broken or misconfigured IPv6 setup, and this will cause problems as web sites enabled Ipv6". So there is definitely something wrong with Apple's DNS64 or my configuration of it. Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me. Are you using iOS 9.2+?

Comment: Normally I run my phone to my mac's hotspot with mac's 6to4 service enabled. What's your setup?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (result == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"worked");
    struct sockaddr_storage stor = *( (struct sockaddr_storage *) addrinfo->ai_addr);

    //
    char host[1024];
    char serv[20];
    struct addrinfo * res = addrinfo;

    getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr), host, sizeof(host), serv, sizeof(serv), NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
    NSString * stringHost = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:host];
    NSString * stringPort = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:serv];

    NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@: %@", res->ai_family == AF_INET ? @"IPv4" : (res->ai_family == AF_INET6 ? @"IPV6" : @"Unknown"), stringHost, stringPort];
    NSLog(@"---- %@", string);  //IPV6: 64:ff9b::cebe:242d
}
```

Comment: When I run my code I always get into the "error" conditional, so your code will never run. result = EAI_NONAME